# circular reference in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have an issue currently I can't wrap my head around.

*Situation*:
In the shops we have gates that count the customers IN and OUT.
These gates sometimes count too much or too few and we want to correct this info for where IN is totally different from OUT.

The total counts for all gates are kept by half hour and per shop.

Below you can find the (Excel) formulas as suggested by the business to make that correction on the data:

eg for the 13th time-frame, the 'IN orig(inal)' is **113** while only **18** customers left the shop.
The corrected value as result of the formula gives **36**.

The text from the formula: =IF(AA88+V89-U89<0;U89;IF(AA88+V89-U89>U90+U91;U90+U91+U89-AA88;V89))

[image]

[image]

These are the most important business definitions of fields found in the screenshots (others are not relevant):

> *Resterende orig op einde van tijdsblok* (dutch) = rest orig by the end of timeframe (ENG translation) = rest corr on the end of previous
>   timeframe + (IN orig from current timeframe - OUT orig from current
>   timeframe)
>
> *Resterende corr op einde van tijdsblok* (dutch) = rest correction on the end of the timeframe (ENG translation) = rest corr on the end of the
>   previous timeframe + (IN corr1 from this timeframe - OUT orig from the
>   current timeframe)

[image]

```
UIT orig    IN orig IN corr1
 -       -       -     
 1       2       2   
 -       1       1   
 9       25      25   
 41      45      45   
 37      38      38   
 51      50      50   
 24      21      21   
 19      12      12   
 18      25      25   
 27      35      35   
 9       81      34   
 18      113     36   
 34      116     35   
 36      123     19   
 35      127     31   
 19      103     16   
 31      79      11   
 16      50      15   
 11      28      2   
 15      16      -     
 2       -       -     
 -       -       -     
 -       -       -     
 -       -       -     
 -       -       -     
 -       -       -     
 -       -       -
```

Above the dataset,

In BLUE the data we have a available

In YELLOW the **result** we need to have in the end.

Below also the T-SQL query,
the "(0)" in the last query is the field with the (kind of) circular reference resides and I can't get solved.

Problem. They use a calculation from one formula in the other formula.
Have a look at in and you'll see it's not that easy. The approach I currently have, see query, is not sufficient to solve the formula, I tried some other options but then came here as they didn't work

Thanks a lot for all help.

```
-- STAP 0: laadt de data in temp table om correcties te doen op de IN waardes aan helemaal het begin & eind van de dag
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stap0', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #stap0

select *
, Teller1IN + Teller2IN as TellersIN
, Teller1UIT + Teller2UIT as TellersUIT
into #stap0
from KlantenTellers
where Datum >= '20180101'

-- gelijkstellen IN aan de UIT (!)
update s0
set Teller1IN = Teller1UIT
, Teller2IN = Teller2UIT
from #stap0 s0
where (convert(varchar, Datum, 8) between '00:00:00' and '08:59:59'  --cast(Datum as time)
OR convert(varchar, Datum, 8) between '21:29:59' and '00:00:00')


-- STAP 1: bereken de 'Resterende orig op einde van tijdsblok' en 'Resterende corr op einde van tijdsblok'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stap1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #stap1

select
* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by WinkelNr,EEYYMMDD ORDER BY Datum asc) AS rownum
, sum(Teller1IN+Teller2IN) OVER (partition by WinkelNr,EEYYMMDD ORDER BY Datum asc) AS RunningTotalIN  --RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
, sum(Teller1UIT+Teller2UIT) OVER (partition by WinkelNr,EEYYMMDD ORDER BY Datum asc) AS RunningTotalUIT 
into #stap1
from #stap0



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stap2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #stap2

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN base.rownum = 1
            THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN base.TellersIN - base.TellersUIT < 0
                            THEN base.TellersUIT
                        ELSE base.TellersIN
                        END
                    )
        WHEN base.rownum > 1
            THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (0) + base.TellersIN - base.TellersUIT < 0
                            THEN base.TellersUIT
                        ELSE CASE 
                                WHEN (0) + base.TellersIN - base.TellersUIT > (base_1.TellersUIT + base_2.TellersUIT)
                                    THEN (base.TellersUIT + base_1.TellersUIT + base_2.TellersUIT) - (0)
                                ELSE base.TellersIN
                                END
                        END
                    )
        END
    ,*
FROM #stap1 base
left outer join #stap1 base_min1 
    on base.WinkelNr = base_min1.WinkelNr and base.EEYYMMDD = base_min1.EEYYMMDD
    and base_min1.rownum = base.rownum-1
left outer join #stap1 base_1 
    on base.WinkelNr = base_1.WinkelNr and base.EEYYMMDD = base_1.EEYYMMDD
    and base_1.rownum = base.rownum+1
left outer join #stap1 base_2 
    on base.WinkelNr = base_2.WinkelNr and base.EEYYMMDD = base_2.EEYYMMDD
    and base_2.rownum = base.rownum+2
left outer join #stap1 base_3 
    on base.WinkelNr = base_3.WinkelNr and base.EEYYMMDD = base_3.EEYYMMDD
    and base_3.rownum = base.rownum+3
where base.WinkelNr = 7
and base.EEYYMMDD = '20180104'
order by base.rownum
```

Comment: What is your question here? What RDBMS are you *really* using; SQL Server <> MySQL. Please don't provide data as images either; we can't use it. Either supply it as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements. Thanks.

Comment: Tks for the reply. It's sql-server. You should have the relevant data (already) as text. Should I upload the excel file somewhere?

My question is help on the query and/or approach

Comment: So... Are you asking how to implement the excel formula in T-SQL?

Comment: Hey Zohar.... No, I'm asking how this logic could be translated. The data is the same (sql or xls): customers going in and out the shop. I have never really gotten a situation where SQL couldn't do the trick (with or without help) so I expect this question can be solved. If not, easily